# Mysql many-to-many получить количество пересечений

Tags: mysql, join

Добрый день! Столкнулся с проблемой и не могу составить корректный запрос в базу (не могу понять логику запроса)
Есть такая схема:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE groups(
    id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE users_groups (
    user_id INT(10) NOT NULL, 
    group_id INT(10) NOT NULL
);

insert into `users` ( `id`, `name`) values 
(1, 'User#1'), (2, 'User#2'), (3, 'User#3'), (4, 'User#4'), (5, 'User#5'), (6, 'User#6'), (7, 'User#7'), (8, 'User#8'), (9, 'User#9'), (10, 'User#10')
;

insert into `groups` ( `id`, `name`) values 
(1, 'Group#1'), (2, 'Group#2'), (3, 'Group#3'), (4, 'Group#4'), (5, 'Group#5')
;

insert into `users_groups` ( `user_id`, `group_id`) values 
(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), 
(2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), 
(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4),
(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4),
(5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), 
(6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 5), 
(7, 1), (7, 4), (7, 5), 
(8, 2), (8, 3), (8, 4), (8, 5), 
(9, 1), (9, 2), (9, 3), (9, 4), (9, 5), 
(10, 2), (10, 4)
;
```

Мне необходимо получить пару пользователей у которых максимальное количество общих групп.

На примере моих данных, это будут пользователи под номером 1 и 9.

Comment: Собственно говоря получение пользователей и списка групп использую такой запрос:
`SELECT u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(g.name) as groups
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN users_groups as ug ON u.id = ug.user_id
LEFT JOIN groups as g ON ug.group_id = g.id
GROUP BY u.id
;`

Comment: `получить TOP-10/50/100 (разными запросами) пользователей у которых максимальное количество общих групп` - в смысле пар пользователей, у которых максимум? или троек? может, вообще по всему массиву? или вообще не из этой оперы? Ну или хотя бы эталонный ответ на показанных данных с минимальным пояснением...

Comment: `получение пользователей и списка групп использую такой запрос` Хреновый запрос. Связывание какое-то левое.

Comment: @Akina а можно пример для пар пользователей? От него уже и буду скакать и думать.

Comment: А количество отличающихся групп надо как то учитывать ? Например у двух пользователей 10 совпадающих и 100 не совпадающих групп, у других двух 9 совпадающих и нет не совпадающих. в ответе нужна первая пара ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если учитывать разницу не надо, а только совпадения, то:

```
select a.user_id, b.user_id, count(1)
  from users_groups a
  join users_groups b on b.group_id=a.group_id and a.user_id<b.user_id
 group by a.user_id, b.user_id
 order by count(1) desc
 limit 1
```

таблицы пользователей и/или групп доклеить по вкусу

Comment: Майк, спасибо большое, это очень похоже на то, что мне необходимо.
А не могли бы мне объяснить логику запроса, если быть точнее я не могу понять как работает условие `a.user_id<b.user_id`

Comment: @Sergius Если вообще не указать этого условия, то пользователь будет сравниваться сам с собой, что даст на выходе просто пользователя у которого больше всего групп. Если написать просто "не равно" что бы этого избежать, то на выходе мы получим задвоение пользователь 1 будет сравнен с 9 и 9й будет сравнен 1м.  и на выходе будут записи "1,9" и "9,1". "Меньше" исключает такую ситуацию, в первой колонке всегда пользователь с меньшим id из двух. Ну и работы БД меньше, не надо сравнивать по 2 раза 1<=>9, 9<=>1

Comment: Большое человеческое спасибо! Вы очень мне помогли разобраться с этой темой!